# The Hage-Che question ending 는가 or 은가

Tags: speech-levels, sentence-endings

I have seen this question in K-dramas quite a lot used in the Hage-che context; when someone in authority [usually a guy] want to ask a junior something.

But as the Hage che is uncommon in the Seoul dialect: does the Hage che connotation still hold true in everyday Korean or has this ending been consumed into Haera che  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do still use variations of ~는가 in the southwestern provinces of the 호남 region, more pronounced in the deep south of 전라남도, even among the relatively younger generations. It's directed from old to young, or used between equals.

밥먹었어? ==> 밥먹었는가?

잘지내? ==> 잘지내는가?

그랬어? ==> 그랬는가?

This form of speech is strictly limited to that region only and to those who're closely acquainted. Someone from 전라남도 wouldn't say these things in Seoul or elsewhere in the country.

Comment: Thank you ! Yes I have notice Hage che and Hao che still survives in dialects other than Standard [Seoul] dialect.